# NHibernate to Linq Get Authors who have not written books

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I am taking the example of Author and Books to make the explanation simple. Author - Book has one to many relation i.e One author can write many books. The mapping is done using **FluentHibernate** and nothing special in them.

I am trying to query for Authors who haven't yet written any books. But when viewing the query generated in NHibernate Profiler, it is not what i expected. Can you guys sort the mistake out

**Results that i expect are from below query**

```
select a.AuthorName
       ,a.AuthorId from Authors a left outer join Books b on a.AuthorId = b.AuthorId
where b.AuthorId is null
```

Actual query generated is as below

```
SELECT AuthorId,
       AuthorName,
       CreatedAt
FROM   Authors
WHERE  AuthorId is null
```

**Mappings Provided For the Above**

```
public class AuthorsMap : ClassMap<Author>
{

    public AuthorsMap()
    {
        Table("Authors");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.AuthorId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("AuthorId");
        Map(x => x.AuthorName).Column("AuthorName").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CreatedAt).Column("CreateDatetime").Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Books).KeyColumn("AuthorId");
    }
}
```

Above is the mapping provided for Authors, below is for the books

```
public class BooksMap : ClassMap<Books>
{
    public BooksMap()
    {
        Table("Books");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.BookId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("BookId");
        References(x => x.Author).Column("AuthorId");
        Map(x => x.BookName).Column("BookName").Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

**Query is Invoked as below**

```
Session.Linq<Author>().Where(author => author.Books == null).ToList();
```

another flavor of above caused Object Reference error

```
Session.Linq<Author>().Where(author => author.Books.Count == 0).ToList();
```

**Performance Problems:**

Answer from @Ocelot20 works, but is generating N + 1 queries to Find the records

`Session.Linq<Author>().Where(author => !author.Books.Any()0).ToList();`

example;

Author 1, 2,3 do not have books then the below queries are run when doing Any()

`SELECT AuthorId,BookId,BookName from Books Where AuthorId = 1`

`SELECT AuthorId,BookId,BookName from Books Where AuthorId = 2`

`SELECT AuthorId,BookId,BookName from Books Where AuthorId = 3`

Now how did this happen !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest to use the **Subquery** instead of *JOIN*. The reason is that once we will need to switch the query to find out Authors having some books, the JOIN will multiply the result set *(Authors with 2 books will be listed twice etc.)*

Also, let's use the NHibernate native Linq provider syntax with the `Query` extension (returning required `IQueryable<>`)
The syntax to achieve that would be:

The subselect:

```
var subquery = session.Query<Book>()
    .Select(b => b.Author.AuthorId)
    ;
```

The set of authors without any book

```
var list = session.Query<Author>()
    .Where(a => !subquery.Contains(a.AuthorId))
    ;
```

If we want get the list of Authors having some books, we can just remove the NOT operator (!) and apply paging (`Take()`, `Skip()`) which will return correct, not multiplied results.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
Session.Linq<Author>().Where(author => !author.Books.Any()).ToList()
```

I see why `author.Books == null` doesn't work, since it should be an empty collection, not just entirely null. I'm not very familiar with nhibernate though, so I can't comment on the configuration. This is just how I would write the query using Linq.

Comment: Well that worked, but but but. It is least performant. I am editing my question to include what happens if i implement `Any()`

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Some quick googling seems to indicate that in nhibernate you need some kind of `fetch` setting in your mapping to indicate that it should use a join in this case.